# programmatic touchdown to UIView (old title: assume user has finger on screen ios)

Tags: ios, objective-c, touch, uipangesturerecognizer

EDIT: Is there any way to programatically touchdown on a UIView?

When the user touches down the UIButton, the appdelegate sets a new rootviewcontroller. The new controller has a screenshot of the last view, and I would like the user to swipe the "view" (image) off the screen. Everything is working perfectly, but I can't seem to engage the UIPanGestureRecognizer until the finger is lifted and then touched down again. So for I've tried to programatically add a UIControlEvent -- in hindsight, that kind of makes no sense.

Anyways, got any ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, you certainly can get a touch down followed by a pan to work on a button if you  add a pan gesture recognizer to the button, and have the button's action set to fire on touch down. I think the proper way to make the transition would be to have the button's touch down method instantiate the new controller, and add its view to the window's subviews. Then, the swipe (or pan) would animate out the old view, switch the root view controller, and finally, remove the old view from the window. With this method, you don't need to use a screenshot, or mess around with trying to pass on that original touch to a new view. Something like this (I used a swipe rather than a pan for simplicity):

```
- (IBAction)touchDownMethod:(UIButton *)sender {

    self.nextVC = [self.storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"NextVC"];
    self.nextVC.view.frame = self.view.frame;
    [self.view.window insertSubview:self.nextVC.view belowSubview:self.view];

}


- (IBAction)SwipeAwayInitialController:(UISwipeGestureRecognizer *)sender {

    [UIView animateWithDuration:.5 animations:^{
        self.view.center = CGPointMake(self.view.center.x - self.view.bounds.size.width, self.view.center.y);
    } completion:^(BOOL finished) {
        self.view.window.rootViewController = self.nextVC;
        [self.view removeFromSuperview];
    }];
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Set a new rootviewcontroller on touch *up* instead of touch *down* and that will solve your problem.

Comment: okay... that was rude, but I'm going to let it slide :P. Do you think it's possible to collect the touch event in the first view and pass it to the second one for the panGesture to use? I'd like to keep the setup this way because of the aesthetic it has for the tintbar (if you'd like I can shoot a video to show exactly what I mean for the program)... or somehow simulate/reenable a touch event?

Comment: also this: panGesture.state = UIGestureRecognizerStateBegan; ... but it's not "active" so it logs this: "Ignoring call to [UIPanGestureRecognizer setTranslation:inView:] since gesture recognizer is not active."

Comment: or instantiating the uipangesturerecognizer in the first view, and passing it over... but I highly doubt this would work because the action would need to be changed

Comment: I'm not trying to be rude.  I just thought that this would be a way for you to get both functionalities.  I don't know of any way to pass touches like that.